# Getting All Facebook Comments from a Single Domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have implemented facebook comment plugins into some of our pages.

And, now, we would like to have page where it will list all the comments made in these pages (or in a single domain)?

Is there actually a way to do this? I noticed that there is the `activity feed` for a single domain but it does not include commenting.

Also, there is a graph api to pull comments from a page using the `GRAPH API` but we have like thousands of pages. To do this would take a lot of time, even though we cache it.

Thus, I wonder if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203158/how-to-list-all-comments-in-my-domain